# How to launch a list of python scripts asynchronously?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I tried making a script that reads an array of scripts directories in it, and launches them asynchronously. The problem in my script is that it launches only the last script in the array.

```
import json 
import asyncio
import firstscript
import secondscript

def main():
    list = json.load(open('list.json'))
    launch_list = []
    for i in range(len(exchanges_list['e'])):
        get_exchange = exchanges_list['e'][i][0]
        launch_exchange = str(get_exchange.lower() + '.' + get_exchange.lower() + '()')
        launch_list.append(launch_exchange)

    async def handle_script(uri):
        exec(uri)
    async def handler():
        await asyncio.wait([handle_socket(uri) for uri in launch_list])
    
    asyncio.run(handler())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not perfectly the solution you asked for, but using Python itself to run concurrent scripts poses some drawbacks (e.g. having real tasks distributed over multiple physical cores on the CPU for each script).

If you're using a UNIX-system with e.g. a bash-shell you can use the `taskset` to run scripts asynchronuously if you do not care to share information between them.
`taskset` even allows you to choose the respective core you want your script to run on.

You could do it like this:

```bash
cd /your/folder/containingTheScripts

taskset --cpu-list 0 python3 yourPythonScript1.py &
taskset --cpu-list 1 python3 yourPythonScript2.py &
taskset --cpu-list 2 python3 yourPythonScript3.py &
taskset --cpu-list 3 python3 yourPythonScript4.py &

wait
```

- The `&` pushes the respective tasks to the background
- `wait` waits until each script has finished.
- `--cpu-list X` lets you choose your physical core

Of course you can also make selecting the script generic etc.
Note: You can also issue these commands directly from Python with the `subprocess`-module.

I hope this at least helps to tackle your issue to some extend :)

Comment: This answer doesn't debug their script, but I'll give +1 for a solution any day